# Report Issue in OpenERP v7

Tags: python, parsing, odoo, openoffice.org, openerp-7

I'm making a new report, from OpenOffice with `base_report_designer` module, on `product` object.

Everything seems ok, but everytime I try to print it, it throws this error:

```
Field 'product' does not exist in object 'browse_record(product.product, 12)'

(<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>, AttributeError(KeyError("Field 'product' does not exist in object 'browse_record(product.product, 12)'",),), <traceback object at 0xc2801e4>)
```

This usually happens when you actually 'save' the document instead of sending to the server, but i'm not doing that, i'm using a parser made by me, using `product.product` model, and it should work, this is my parser:

```
import time
from openerp.report import report_sxw
class reporte_locacion(report_sxw.rml_parse):
def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
    super(reporte_locacion, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
    self.localcontext.update({
         'time': time,
         'qty_total':self._qty_total
    })

def _qty_total(self, objects):
    total = 0.0
    uom = objects[0].product_uom.name
    for obj in objects:
        total += obj.product_qty
    return {'quantity':total,'uom':uom}


report_sxw.report_sxw(
'report.reporte.locacion',
'product.product',
'addons/stock/report/reporte_locacion.rml',
parser=reporte_locacion,
header='internal'
)
```

And my report (sxw format, it has an .rml version):

```
[[ repeatIn(objects,'o') ]] 
Stock Inventory

Inventory
Date
[[ o.name ]]
[[ formatLang(o.date,date_time=True) ]]

Location
Production Lot
Product 
Quantity
[[ repeatIn(o.product, 'p') ]]
[[ p.location_id.name ]]
[[ p.prod_lot_id  and p.prod_lot_id.name or '' ]]
[ [[ p.product_id.code ]] ] [[ p.product_id.name ]]
[[ formatLang(p.product_qty) ]] [[ p.product_uom.name ]]

Total:
[[ formatLang(qty_total(o.inventory_line_id)['quantity']) ]] [[ qty_total(o.inventory_line_id)['uom'] ]]
```

Can't figure it out, it should loop on `product` I don't get it, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o is a object of Product. You can get value of product for example [[ o. name_template ]] it will return product name.

You are trying to use [[ o.product ]] but in product.product object their is no field name *product*

*repeatIn* is used for looping in RML for example you have to list of record (one2many field) and here is syntax.

```
[[ repeatIn(o.one2many_field_name, 'p') ]]
```

For *repeatIn*, you need to have list of object (one2many) and than it will get value properly.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that's the path to follow, I'll then create some relationships to get my job done! Thank you very much!